# Send temp data from View to Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code in my View Jquery portion:

```
$('#btnContinue').click(function () {                  

     var createFormName = $("#createFormName");
     createFormName.submit();
}
```

I like to send a temp data from the view to the controller as I need to redirect the user inside the controller's action result based on the temp data value. Is there a way to send temp data from the view to the controller's action result?

Comment: I can't really see a justification for doing this bc I would think you would just want to add a hidden form field with the value and send it off with the form post submission but you could go old school and set a cookie in js and retrieve it from the controller's method within the http context. That's how temp data is coming from server to client on the backend anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Let's Offer 2 approaches shown with easy examples:**

The quickest way is to send it through query String. like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TempData["message"] = "Hi";

        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult About(string str1, string str2) { . . . }
```

then, in your index view:

```
@{
     string str = TempData["message"].ToString();                            
     @Html.ActionLink("Go to About View", "About", new  { str1 =  @str, str2="some text"})
}
```

On the other hand, you can Post you data to controller, rather than sending via query string; 
Let's imagine we have a simple view model here:

```
public class DoubleStr_ViewModel
{
    public string  str1 { get; set; }
    public string  str2 { get; set; }
}
```

then inside the controller:

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        TempData["message"] = "Hi";            
        return View(new DoubliStr_ViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult About(DoubleStr_ViewModel input)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And now, inside the About View:

```
@using Your.Path.To.ViewModels
@model  DoubleStr_ViewModel

<input type="hidden" value="@TempData["message"].ToString()" id="tmpHidden" />

<form method="post">
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.str1)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.str2)
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>



@section scripts{
    <script>

        $('form').submit(function () {

            $('input#str1').val($('input#tmpHidden').val());
        });
    </script>
    }
```

In your case, to trigger form submit, you'll have:

```
$('#btnContinue').click(function () {                  

     // first, fill the hidden value(s) into your model
     $('input#str1').val($('input#tmpHidden').val());

     var createFormName = $("#createFormName");          
     createFormName.submit();
}
```

Hope, this helps.